# Defined method in my jQuery plugin return's the error : undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, and I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (repeated 8 times)` for the method `_setProgress()` that it is defined.

My plugin code is the following:

```
;(
function($, window, document, undefined)
{
    var pluginName          =   "imageSlider2";
    var defaults            =   {
        onImagesLoaded : undefined,
        onComplete     : undefined
    };

    var max_image_height    =   null;

    function Plugin(element, options)
    {
        this.element    =   element;
        this.settings   =   $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults  =   defaults;
        this._name      =   pluginName;

        this._init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        _init   :   function()
        {
            $(document).on(
                'images-loaded',
                function(e)
                {
                    //_hideProgress();
                }
            );

            $(document).on(
                'slides-initiated',
                function(e)
                {
                    //_animationStart();
                }
            );

            this._hideAny();
            this._addProgress();
        },
        _hideAny    :   function()
        {
            ...
        },
        _randomID   :   function()
        {
            ...
        },
        _addProgress    :   function()
        {
            ...
            // This method just injecting an HTML element in my document

            this._imagePreload()
        },
        _setProgress    :   function(progress)
        {
            ...
        },
        _imagePreload   :   function()
        {
            ...

            $percent = 25;
            this._setProgress($percent);

            ...
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName]    =   function(options)
    {
        var plugin;

        this.each(
            function()
            {
                plugin  =   $.data(this,    "plugin_" + pluginName);

                if(!plugin)
                {
                    plugin  =   new Plugin(this, options);

                    $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,    plugin);
                }
            }
        );

        return plugin;
    };
}
)(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suspect since you override the prototype as a whole, therefore missing the constructor. Better try to assign prototype methods separately like

```
 Plugin.prototype._init  = function(){}
```

Or

Set the constructor again like

```
 Plugin.prototype.constructor  = Plugin;
```

Comment: This will solve my problem or is it a better structure for my plugin ?